# How to create a single PDF from multiple PDF files in C# without using any 3rd party library?

Tags: c#

I have a client requirement, in which we have multiple pdf attachments present with each of the Opportunity Record in Dynamics CRM.  Whenever end user needs documents; he/she has to download multiple files each time. 
The requirement is to download all the files as a single pdf file. Also, the files from second file has to be appended one after the other.

Comment: And why can't you use a 3rd party library ? Really ?

Comment: Maybe you could let them download those PDFs as single **ZIP** file instead of PDF. That would be **far** easier to do if you can't use an external library.

Comment: As I mentioned, I need this for Dynamics CRM , and I have to use this custom code in a plugin. The plugin cannot be registered on Dynamics CRM with any third party dll. I faced this even with NewtonSoft dll, so I had used other option at that time.

Comment: Not only would a zip file containing all the documents be easier to code, it would also most likely be a much better experience for the customer. Then they just can keep what they want, plus print or share individual documents, without the need to search the combined PDF for what what they want and copy parts out of it.

Comment: They don't want a zip, they want a better user friendly approach. User would just click on button to download and read all files at once, as there is a single file :)

Comment: As I commented above, I don't see that as a more user-friendly approach. Did that request come from the users themselves, or from a PM or other entity?

Comment: Requirement came from client's higher authority

Comment: As I expected. I would bet that the clients will absolutely hate it.

Comment: Docs will come at any time, and uploaded to existing docs collection so a zip will not help

Comment: I don't believe there is **any** PDF functionality [included within C#/.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?search=pdf&scope=.NET), so you may have to push back on the requirement anyway, if you can't use a third-party library.

Comment: Thanks @stuartd , I will discuss this with my PM, lets see what could be done. If found/resolved, I will post our final solution to this soon.

Comment: Apiologies for replying too late on this .. We implemented a Web API to utilize ITextSharp for combining PDF files [As we couldn't use it inside plugin (We didn't want to use IL Merge for plugin to include third party DLL)]. The Web API is accessing the SharePoint Document Location using SharePoint CSOM, reading the FileContent, Combining multiple PDF, responding the Base64 File Content. This Web API we are calling through a custom action in CRM.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin is the wrong way to do this:

- The code to accomplish this is not very plugin compatible. Merging documents requires some level of interaction with an operating system (i.e. reading and writing files). You could probably hack your way through this with ILMerge and a non-sandboxed plugin, but the result would only work with on-premise CRM and would not be supported by Microsoft.
- Plugins are server side and must trigger on a database action. It sounds like you want a user friendly process which produces this combined document which suggests a client facing application. Your client side program could cause some CRUD operation which triggers this plugin, then retrieve the resulting file, but that is unnecessarily complicated.

Write a web page which generates the document and provides it to the user as a file download dialogue. Call your application from a button within CRM.